# Integrate $\int x e^{x} \sin x dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate:
>
> $$\int x e^{x} \sin x dx$$

Have you ever come across such an integral? I have no idea how to start with the calculation.

Comment: Where did such an integral come from? Here is an answer: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+x+sin(x)+e%5Ex

Comment: I'm doing some calculations which are based on Schrodingers equation (of course some things are simplified). Thanks!

Comment: HINT:  Use Euler's Formula to write $$x\sin(x)e^x=\text{Im}(xe^{(1+i)x})$$

Comment: I'd recommend integration by parts. You'll have to do it twice. Euler's theorem will help.

Comment: @jaustin: You integrate by parts twice for $\int x \sin x$ or $\int x \Bbb e^x$ or $\int \Bbb e ^x x$, but here you have all these three functions in the integrand, so it's a bit longer then that.

Comment: I don't think that integration by parts is necessary here... Differentiation under the integral sign should suffice once we write in complex exponential form.

Comment: I'd do this by calculating the derivative of $xe^x\sin x$, as well as the derivative of other terms that might appear in the answer such as $xe^x\cos x$, $e^x\sin x$, and $e^x\cos x$. Then, I'd try to see if I can write your integrand ($xe^x\sin dx$) as a sum of this derivatives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution without complex numbers:

Let $I=\int e^x x\sin xdx$ Integrating by parts:

$$I=e^x x\sin x-\int e^x x\cos xdx-\int e^x\sin xdx$$

Then one more time by parts:

$$\int e^x x\cos xdx=e^x x\cos x + I-\int e^x\cos xdx$$

So:

$$2I=e^x x\sin x-e^x x\cos x+\int e^x(\cos x-\sin x)dx$$

Now (by parts again or by direct observation):

$$\int e^x(\cos x-\sin x)dx=e^x \cos x$$

So:

$$I=\frac{e^x x\sin x-e^x x\cos x+e^x \cos x}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate this solution because I didn't want to use complex numbers. It's a nice one :)

Answer (score 10):

If one may recall that $\sin(x)=\Im e^{ix}$, then

$$\int x\sin(x)e^x\ dx=\Im\int xe^{(1+i)x}\ dx$$

With a quick integration by parts, we have

$$=\Im\left(\frac1{1+i}xe^{(1+i)x}-\frac1{1+i}\int e^{(1+i)x}\ dx\right)\\=\Im\left(\frac1{1+i}xe^{(1+i)x}-\frac1{(1+i)^2}e^{(1+i)x}+C\right)\\=\frac12\left(x\sin(x)e^x-x\cos(x)e^x+\cos(x)e^x\right)$$

Comment: Very nice solution! And it's pretty short. Thanks :)

Comment: @Hendrra No problem.  Shortness and all that good stuff comes with using complex numbers, so I highly recommend you learn it a bit, maybe just for checking your work ;-)

Comment: I think I should learn how to use complex numbers a bit! Sometimes it's great to know some shorters ways of doing something. Can you recommend me some textbooks, please?

Comment: Oh... uh.. see, I haven't read any textbooks.  Especially any about complex numbers.  I'll have to recommend you look up "Euler's formula" though:$$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$which was the basis of my answer.  @Hendrra

Comment: Thank you! That formula is amazingly beautiful for $x = \pi$

Comment: @Hendrra $100%$ beautify for all $x$ IMO.  Particularly enough values of $x$ so that I can cheat all my integrals and summations that involve trig functions ;)

Comment: I think it should be $+\cos x$ at the end, otherwise it's good.

Comment: @Momo Thanks, a lot of sign changes happening at the end there.

Answer (score 4):

**HINTS:**

Use Euler's Formula to write $$x\sin(x)e^x=\text{Im}(xe^{(1+i)x})$$Integrate $\int xe^{(1+i)x}\,dx$ by parts with $u=x$ and $v=\frac{e^{(1+i)x}}{1+i}$ and finish by taking the imaginary part.

Answer (score 3):

This solution doesn't use integration by parts. We start with

$$\int\exp(x) dx = \exp(x)$$

Substituting  $x = \lambda t$ yields:

$$\int\exp(\lambda t) dt = \frac{\exp(\lambda t)}{\lambda}$$

Substitute $\lambda = 1+\epsilon + i$ and expand both sides to first order in $\epsilon$. Equating the coefficient of $\epsilon$ of both sides yields:

$$\begin{split}\int t\exp(t)\exp(i t) dt &= \exp(t)\exp(it)\left[\frac{1-i}{2}t + \frac{i}{2}\right]\\
& = \exp(t)\left[\frac{\exp(i(t-\frac{\pi}{4}))}{\sqrt{2}}t + \frac{\exp(i(t+\frac{\pi}{2}))}{2}\right]
\end{split}
$$

Finally, take the imaginary part of both sides:

$$\int t\exp(t)\sin(t) dt = \exp(t)\left[\frac{\sin\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}t + \frac{\cos(t)}{2}\right]$$

Answer (score 3):

This can also be solved another way (a little longer but correct nevertheless and could be more basic and readable for people who just started learning calculus):

We will use the results of following(easy - just substitute):

$$
∫ e^x \sin (x) dx = \frac{e^x \sin (x) - e^x \cos (x)}{2} + C
$$

$$
∫ e^{\ln (x)+x}dx = ∫ xe^xdx = xe^x-e^x + C
$$
and

$$
∫ e^x \cos (x) dx = \frac{e^x \sin (x) + e^x \cos (x)}{2} + C
$$

Now, back to the main integral. The main problem is that the formula contains not the usual two but three factors($x$, $e^x$ and $\sin (x)$). However, using basic logarithm and $\exp $ properties we can transform the \exp ression into one with just two factors:

$$
x e^x = e^{\ln (x)} e^x = e^{\ln (x) + x}
$$

this leaves us with

\begin{equation*}
I =
\int xe^xsinx dx =
\int e^{ln(x) + x} \sin (x) dx =
\end{equation*}

integrate by parts with substituting:

$$
\begin{equation*}
\left[
 \begin{alignedat}{2}
 u &= \sin (x) \quad & du &=\cos (x) \\
 dv &= e^{\ln (x)+x} \quad & v &= xe^x-e^x
 \end{alignedat}\,
\right] 
\end{equation*}
$$

$$
= e^xx\sin (x)-e^x\sin (x)-∫ xe^x\cos (x) -e^x\cos (x)dx 
$$

$$
= e^xx\sin (x)-e^x\sin (x)-∫ xe^x\cos (x)dx + ∫ e^x\cos (x)dx
$$

Now, another three factor integral appears, which can also be integrated by parts using the previous trick.

$$
∫ xe^x\cos (x)dx = 
$$
$$
\begin{equation*}
= ∫ e^{\ln (x)+x}\cos (x)dx = 
\left[
 \begin{alignedat}{2}
 u &= \cos (x) \quad & du &=-\sin (x) \\
 dv &= e^{\ln (x)+x} \quad & v &= xe^x-e^x
 \end{alignedat}\,
\right] =
\end{equation*}
$$
$$
= xe^x\cos (x)-e^x\cos (x)+ ∫ x e^x \sin (x) dx - ∫ e^x \sin (x) dx =
$$
$$
= xe^x\cos (x)-e^x\cos (x)+ I - ∫ e^x \sin (x) dx 
$$

Back to the previous equation, plug in the result above flipping the signs accordingly:

$$
I = e^xx\sin (x)-e^x\sin (x) + ∫ e^x\cos (x)dx - xe^x\cos (x)+e^x\cos (x)- I + ∫ e^x \sin (x) dx
$$
Great! We obtained the wanted integral with negative sign. Let's move it to the other side of equation:
$$
2I = e^xx\sin (x)-e^x\sin (x) + ∫ e^x\cos (x)dx - xe^x\cos (x)+e^x\cos (x) + ∫ e^x \sin (x) dx
$$
and plug in the results of simpler integrals:
$$
2I = e^xx\sin (x)-e^x\sin (x) + \frac{e^x \sin (x) + e^x \cos (x)}{2} - xe^x\cos (x)+e^x\cos (x) + \frac{e^x \sin (x) - e^x \cos (x)}{2} + C
$$
now just simplify the right side and divide by 2 to obtain the final result:
$$
I = \frac {xe^x\sin (x) - xe^x\cos (x) +e^x\cos (x)}{2} + C
$$

Answer (score 1):

**By indeterminate coefficients**:

A term like $xe^x\sin x$ can be generated by the derivative of itself (due to $e^x$), which will also generate $xe^x\cos x$ and $e^x\sin x$.

Then we are tempted to try

$$f(x)=e^x(x(A\sin x+B\cos x)+(C\sin x+D\cos x)),$$

and

$$f'(x)=e^x(x(A\sin x+B\cos x)+(C\sin x+D\cos x)+(A\sin x+B\cos x)+x(A\cos x-B\sin x)+(C\cos x-D\sin x)).$$

We identify,

$$A-B=1,\\A+B=0,\\C+A-D=0,\\D+B+C=0$$

and obtain

$$\frac12xe^x(\sin x-\cos x)+\frac12\cos x.$$

Answer (score 0):

First integrate $\sin(x) \exp(x),$ by parts, with the exponential as $d v.$ (you will need to do the integration by parts twice), then use the same method for the original integral.